# Database SubmitChanges() in C# with Linq not working

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update a record in my SQL database. I have 2 updates to different tables in the same database. 1 works fine and the other does not update on the SubmitChanges(). The code looks the same is there something i am missing?

```
public bool UpdateStockSizeInBomData(string drawingNumber, string stockSize)
    {
        using (var db = GetFordContext())
        {
            Data.BomData result = db.BomDatas.Where(b => b.sIdNoStk.Equals(drawingNumber)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (null == result)
            {
                return false;
            }

            result.sDimensionsStk = stockSize;
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This one does not work. The database record comes in fine while debugging, and even changes but the update is never committed to the database. And there has been changes made.

```
public bool UpdateStockSizeInDrawingData(string jobNumber, string drawingNumber, string stockSize, string material)
    {
        using (var db = GetFordContext())
        {
            Data.DrawingData result = db.DrawingDatas.Where(dd => dd.GROB_TB_DrawingNumber.Equals(drawingNumber) && dd.Ford_Vendor_JobNumber.Equals(jobNumber)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (null == result)
            {
                return false;
            }

            result.Ford_Det_StockSize = stockSize;
            //result.Ford_Det_Material = material;
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure someone is going to ask the obvious and yes it does have a primary key

Comment: Could you clarify "..record comes in fine when and even changes.."? Can you profile the database and see what SQL it is getting hit with?

Comment: @Crowcoder I edit the question.

Comment: Can you profile the database?

Comment: Let me guess: you have a .mdf LocalDB in your project directory that gets copied to bin on build. Your application works correctly, the changes simply aren't persisted to the database you're checking. The same goes for if MySQL really is a relevant tag: you're querying the wrong database. If not, information is missing from this question.

Comment: The mysql tag was wrongly added. The database i am using is in SSMS, not just a local db and i am not querying the wrong database. What exactly are you asking for when you say can i profile the database? @Crowcoder

Comment: If you are using SSMS, go to Tools > SQL Server Profiler. Do a little reading if you have no idea what to do, but by using the defaults you should be able to see the sql that EF is throwing at your database. You can look at it and possibly see why the update may not be changing any data.

Comment: I can see it issue the select command but it does not pick up the update command at all.

Comment: Then the context doesn't think the entity has changes or the entity is somehow not attached, hard to say. As a test, update more properties and see if it fires.

Comment: @Crowcoder may be on to something. If `stocksize` is equal to th eoriginal `stocksize`, nothing will happen.

Comment: Do you know that you are getting back a valid result and not a stub/empty default result? Depending on other frameworks you have in place it's possible FirstOrDefault() is returning an empty entity instead of a null one, so there would be no changes to submit since you're changes would be against an unattached entity.

Comment: I am getting back a full result and there are changes being made. It's probably something stupid and little but i can't find anything.